# On drawing there's standardized normal distribution density diagram. Which formulas express value of area field colored wtih green?

Tags: probability, gaussian

[image: Text]

**a)** $\int_{2}^{-1}\Phi (x)dx$, $\Phi$ - distribution $N(0,1)$

**b)** $\int_{2}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}}dx$

**c)** $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{^{\frac{-1^{2}}{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{^{\frac{2^{2}}{2}}}$

**d)** $\Phi(2)+\Phi(1)$, $\Phi$ - distribution $N(0,1)$

**e)** $\Phi(2)+\Phi(1)-1$, $\Phi$ - distribution $N(0,1)$

So its Gaussian distribution with parameter $(-1,2)$

Formula for depth:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{^{\frac{-(x-\mu )^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}}$
, $\mu \in R, \sigma>0$

I don't really understand this, I would bet on **c)** since it has pow $-1$ and $2$,

$e^{^{\frac{-1^{2}}{2}}}$ + $e^{^{\frac{2^{2}}{2}}}$ which are parameters of this distribution...

But there might be more then 1 correct answer so I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't c), because that is just the normal density evaluated at two points. The graph is clearly showing area under the curve, i.e., the integral of the density, which is represented by the CDF. Also, the parameters of the distribution are not $-1$ and $2$, since the peak of the curve is clearly at zero (indeed your first sentence says that it is a standard normal distribution).

Since $\Phi\left(x\right) = P\left(X \leq x\right)$ is the integral of the density from $-\infty$ to $x$, the area shown here can be written as

$$\Phi\left(2\right) - \Phi\left(-1\right).$$

However, that is not one of your options. But, by the symmetry of the normal distribution, $P\left(X < -x\right) = P\left(X > x\right)$. You can use this fact to convert the above expression into one of the given options.

Comment: would **b)** $\int_{2}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}}dx$ be correct if integral had values reversed? like this:  $\int_{-1}^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}}dx$

Comment: Yes -- the area under the curve is the integral of the standard normal density from $-1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the following:

$$\int_{-1}^{2}\phi(t)dt=\Phi(2)-\Phi(-1)=\Phi(2)-[1-\Phi(1)]=\Phi(2)+\Phi(1)-1$$

thus the correct one is e)

All other answers are wrong:

a) inverted integral extremes and integrand CDF

b) quite correct but inverted integral extremes

c) it is not a probability, it is only the sums of two densities

d) as shown in my proof, incorrect

Comment: Could you check 4 more graphs? I have exam tomorrow, its guaranteed task and I am still confused about some things. 
https://imgur.com/a/YLpVATx For example in graph 1) I think 3 answers could be right , but everyone tells me that on graph task there's usually 2 answers to mark.
is d) and a) in graph 1) the same thing?

Comment: @fakerakerp : the confusion is because $\phi$ indicates the density while $\Phi$ indicates the CDF. in graph 1) d) is wrong because the integrand is $\Phi$ while it should be $\phi$. For the same reason in graph 4) the correct answers are a) and c). your d) answer should be correct if it was $\Phi(1)$

Comment: In graph 4) I think person who rewrote answers didn't notice the symbol too. d) was marked because $\Phi(-\infty) = 0$ so $\Phi(1) - 0$ =  d)

Comment: So it would mean that a graph can have more then 2 answers right? Or is c) wrong because its actually $\Phi$ and not $\phi$

Comment: @fakerakerp : I repeat. in graph 4 the correct answers are only 2: a) and c) because $\phi(x)$ is the same expression as the integrand in a)